# Python: How do I convert file to custom base number and back?

Tags: python, python-3.x, radix

I have a file that I want to convert into custom base (base 86 for example, with custom alphabet)

I have try to convert the file with hexlify and then into my custom base but it's too slow... 8 second for 60 Ko..

```
def HexToBase(Hexa, AlphabetList, OccurList, threshold=10):
    number = int(Hexa,16) #base 16 vers base 10
    alphabet = GetAlphabet(AlphabetList, OccurList, threshold)
    #GetAlphabet return a list of all chars that occurs more than threshold times

    b_nbr = len(alphabet) #get the base
    out = ''
    while number > 0:
        out = alphabet[(number % b_nbr)] + out
        number = number // b_nbr
    return out

file = open("File.jpg","rb")
binary_data = file.read()
HexToBase(binascii.hexlify(binary_data),['a','b'],[23,54])
```

So, could anyone help me to find the right solution ?

Sorry for my poor English I'm French, and Thank's for your help !

Comment: When you say _"from binary to custom base"_ you mean convert each byte in the source file to an arbitrary base, or taking into the account the whole file value into an arbitrary base (and if so what's the byte order, i.e. big endian, little endian, custom encoding...)?

Comment: If you do not show your current code, and the problems it has, we cannot help you to improve it...

Comment: I want the same output as hexlify, so i think taking into the account the whole file value into an arbitrary base.

Comment: Byte order is normally Little endian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can replace:

```
int(binascii.hexlify(binary_data), 16) # timeit: 14.349809918712538
```

By:

```
int.from_bytes(binary_data, byteorder='little') # timeit: 3.3330371951720164
```

Second you can use the `divmod` function to speed up the loop:

```
out = ""
while number > 0:
    number, m = divmod(number, b_nbr)
    out = alphabet[m] + out

# timeit: 3.8345545611298126 vs 7.472579440019706
```

For `divmod` vs `%, //` comparison and large numbers, see [Is divmod() faster than using the % and // operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079879/is-divmod-faster-than-using-the-and-operators).

(Remark: I expected that buildind an array and then making a string with `"".join` would be faster than `out = ... + out` but that was not the case with CPython 3.6.)

Everything put together gave me a speed up factor of 6.

Comment: Thanks that's really helped me, I have changed all my code with your tips and now I can encrypt a 60 Ko files with custom base and custom cypher in less than a second ! if you're curious > https://pypi.org/project/NimingCypher/