# Python recursion (format issue)

Tags: python

> Write a recursive function `replace_digit(n, d, r)` which replaces each occurrence of digit `d` in the number `n` by `r`.
>
> `replace_digit(31242154125, 1, 0)` => `30242054025`

My code is as such

```
def replace_digit(n, d, r):
    y=str(n)
    if len(y)==0:
        return ''
    else:
        if y[0]== str(d):
            return str(r) + replace_digit(str(n)[1:],d,r)
        else:
            return y[0]+ replace_digit(str(n)[1:],d,r)
```

However, the answer I get is in a string format. Any idea how to convert into an integer format? I have been stuck for quite some time on this :(

Comment: Return an integer (`int(string_value)`), and convert the returned value *from a recursive call* to a string again.

Comment: Ah, there is a problem there: numbers starting with `0` are going to lose that digit. Do you have any further instructions as for what direction you need to process the numbers in?

Comment: Not really, I just need to get the number shown, where '1's become '0's

Answer (score 1):

If your recursive function must return an integer, then *return integers*. You can always convert the returned integer back into a string for recursive calls.

You'll have to stop when you run out of digits *before* calling, so only recurse if there are 2 or more characters in `y`.

However, this approach a big problem: **leading zeros are dropped when converting to `int()`**:

```
>>> int('025')
25
```

You have two options here:

- Pad the number when you convert to a string (using [`str.zfill()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) or [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format), and use the length of the value you passed into the recursive call).
- Recurse *from the end*. This would also allow you to *not use strings*.

Here is an approach using zero-padding:

```
def replace_digit(n, d, r):
    nstr = str(n)
    first, rest = nstr[0], nstr[1:]
    if rest:
        rest = str(replace_digit(rest, d, r)).zfill(len(rest))
    if first == str(d):
        first = str(r)
    return int(first + rest)
```

Note that you always want to separate out the first character from the tail *anyway*, so I used variables for both.

This way, you can use `if rest:` to guard against recursing when there are no digits left, and you can call `str()` on the return value. The function returns the `int()` conversion of the (possibly replaced first value) with the updated `rest` value.

Demo:

```
>>> replace_digit(31242154125, 1, 0)
30242054025
```

Recursing from the *opposite end* would not have problems with zeros, *except* if the input value was `0` to begin with.  However, you could instead use *division and modules operations* to work on the integer value directly:

- `number % 10` gives you the right-most digit, as an integer.
- `number // 10` gives you the remaining numbers, again as integer.

You could combine the two operations into one using the [`divmod()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod). Personally, I don't do so, as I don't think it particularly improves readability, and [using the operators is slightly faster when using CPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079879/is-divmod-faster-than-using-the-and-operators/30079965#30079965).

You can re-combine the recursive call result with the (possibly replaced) last digit by multiplying the returned value by 10 again:

```
def replace_digit(n, d, r):
    head, last = n // 10, n % 10
    if head:
        head = replace_digit(head, d, r)
    if last == d:
        last = r
    return (head * 10) + last
```

This works for any natural number, including 0:

```
>>> replace_digit(0, 1, 0)
0
>>> replace_digit(0, 0, 1)
1
>>> replace_digit(31242154125, 1, 0)
30242054025
>>> replace_digit(31242154125, 4, 9)
31292159125
```

Comment: Is there any way that there can be a code similar to mine? I'm still kind of foreign to zero-padding

Comment: @WeiHan: that's for you to do yourself, sorry. I gave you all the options on how to solve this properly.