# output converting from int to hex is not as expected, reason?

Tags: python, types

```
int_val = 6074967776560871829
hex_val = []
for i in range(0,8):
    hex_val.append(hex(int_val % 256))
    int_val = int(int_val / 256)
print (hex_val)
```

output is :

```
['0x95', '0xf8', '0xda', '0x97', '0x1', '0x9f', '0x4e', '0x54']
```

but actually it should have been:

```
['0x95', '0xf9', '0xda', '0x97', '0x1', '0x9f', '0x4e', '0x54']
```

why is this difference? can anyone explain why and how to get the right result.

I am trying to send 64 bit integer through modbus using 8 byte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
int_val = int(int_val / 256)
```

The result of the division is a float and there are known limitations, see the often mentioned thread: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Use an integer division:

```
int_val = int_val // 256
```

or its short form `//=` or even better the `divmod` that gives you both results (quotient and remainder) and makes your program shorter and <strike>quicker</strike>. UPDATE: in reality it is not quicker, see the explanation here: [Is divmod() faster than using the % and // operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079879/is-divmod-faster-than-using-the-and-operators) (thanks to Kelly Bundy for testing)

Comment: Using `divmod`, even using a single-letter variable for the remainder, is six characters **longer** for me. And it's about 10% **slower**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [my code](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVNBTsMwEJQ4-hV7QbFRaJOoJG2kvKSqUCA2tSBOlLhVUcVLuPQCd-6ceAAP4BU8gfXGoXDgRi6xd8czs7v243N7b9eNORyeNladzz9OPlXX1GB1LbUFXbdNZ_2OUaa3pdW91df9mK1laUKMV3LL2HVTyRgKCIKAaWMvt-Ud7tIomy3SLMvSizSaZ_E8WbC13PnscsVU04EGbaArzY3kUTgXOQP8PGpStq00FcctH2lPIblIhSDYGJtOCxdlTp68JP_oxXOEsENgpbd1U_HvmPPyl-MduiRHamOwb-iI2hSEwyJxGRR1a6dLqEGy7VCA30nDJXJyhxAiJKRgzM3F0e1VjsbBcahvggdWSUXj6rnyFViHXlo4g1imhLcO3-MYZcWJbqlWYpnH0WpFJzppNx0yBns3Zm57kaeTRD3A2wvsaeYUm1Hs_bUHX8vlsYFxFHn53waHGNlCV8MdG8pUWKLZ1FeyK_BwJGAK7n_Ee6Njj60YRNWPYkgihFt5X1APxM-Gjl0JQYnh4vv7P76DLw)

Comment: @KellyBundy really conterintuitive, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue.
In python, `int_val = int(int_val / 256)` and `int_val //= 256` are different, but I don't know why it is different. With `int_val //= 256` it worked

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).